# Replace image in an element

Tags: apache-flex

I'm a Flex and ActionScript neophyte, but I have the task of replacing an element on a Flex page based on a query string. In other words, the user can pass in a parameter, such as ?image=dog.png, and the ActionScript will replace an image with what the user passed in. The whole page is laid out in an .mxml file. The placeholder image (which is transparent) needs to be replaced by what the user specified. The image they pass in will always be present in the SWF file.

I've tried several things, but none have worked. For example, I tried changing the image's source):

```
view.BlankImage.source = "@Embed(source='/resources/myNewImage.png')";
```

I also tried inserting an image that is initially hidden, assuming I could make it visible at runtime. But the Flex includes the hidden image in its page formatting, so placement of everything is all messed up, even if I never show the hidden image.

Here is the pertinent mxml:

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" bottom="0" horizontalAlign="right">
<mx:Image id="BlankSpot" source="@Embed(source='/resources/blank.medium.png')"
    visible="{!someParameter}" includeInLayout="{BlankSpot.visible}"/>
    <toolbars:SearchBox id="searchBox"/>
</s:VGroup>
```

Any idea how I can replace the image at runtime? Do I need to provide more info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A little more information will help. I'm assuming the images are coming from the web and are NOT all embedded in the application.

If thats the case you can just pass your image a url to the new .png.

Try `BlankSpot.source = "http://someurl.com/image.png`

**Edit**

Since you stated all the images are embedded with your application you can replace the web url with a relative path.

Maybe something like this:

```
var img:String = "dog.png";
BlankSpot.source = "/resources/" + img;
```

If you have a set number of images you can also define and embed them beforehand. A good way to handle this would be to create a Resources class that holds all your embeded assets.

```
package {
    public final class Resources {
        [Embed (source="/resources/dog.png")] public static const DOG:Class;
      }
}
```

You could then use this directly in your image's source

```
BlankSpot.source = Resources.DOG;
```

Also it looks like you're using Flex 4 due to the `<s:VGroup>` so you should switch over to spark images as well.

If there isn't a specific reason for using a mx image here replace that block with

```
<s:Image id="BlankSpot" source="@Embed(source='/resources/blank.medium.png')"
visible="{!someParameter}" includeInLayout="{BlankSpot.visible}"/>
```

Comment: The images will be included in the SWF. What the user will actually pass in is an ID, such as "Image1" or "Image2" and whatever they specify is the image I'll show. If they specify and invalid image, I'll just ignore it.

I don't really know why a <s:VGroup> is being used, but I think it has to do with the search box--the search box and the image need to align together.

Specifying a new image like you show above I had already tried, and it doesn't do a thing. :(

I'm not sure what spark images is, but changing the <mx:Image to <s:Image like you recommend gives me an error in IntelliJ. :(

Comment: @Frecklefoot Since you're using Spark components you should be using at least Flex 4. Try importing spark.components.Image; It also could be that your image is not visible. Have you checked this?

Comment: I tried importing spark.components.Image, but IntelliJ can't resolve it--it says it's not a valid import. So I can't change the mx Image type to a Spark Image. I checked; as far as I can tell, the image is visible.

Comment: @Frecklefoot regardless of Spark or MX image tags any of these approaches will work